# How to wrap input xsml in c data using xslt

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

input to the xslt will be like below:

```html
<cd>
 <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
 <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
 <country>USA</country>
 <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
```

Output of the xsl should be like below:

```html
<Output>
<![CDATA[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
]]>
</Output>
```

I have written below code but < and > are not replacing with < > in the output.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="output">
<output> 
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text> 
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt; </xsl:text> 
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text> 
</output>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="$output"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to create CDATA out of variable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="output">
            <cd>
                <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
                <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
                <country>USA</country>
                <company>Columbia</company>
                <price>10.90</price>
                <year>1985</year>
            </cd>
        </xsl:variable>

        <output>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#x0a;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$output"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#x0a;]]&gt;</xsl:text> 
        </output>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

CDATA sections are really just an alternate escaping mechanism: at an XML level your desired result is the `<Output/>` element with text content that happens to be the serialized output.  DataPower includes a [`<dp:serialize/>` extension](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.7.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/serialize_element.html) that can do this.

I think a working stylesheet should look something like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    extension-element-prefixes="dp"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions">
  <xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="Output"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Output>
      <dp:serialize select="."/>
    </Output>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(This has always been a little bit odd construction, because you can embed XML in XML directly; if you control the application and schema you might consider trying to change it so you don't need to XML parse the text content of an XML element.)